# Naming Service Startup Jacorb

Tags: corba, jacorb, iiop

I have question that when I start `org.jacorb.naming.NameServer` on my machine. It gives me an IOR.

My machine had 2 IP's:

- Private like 192.168.64.39
- Public like 209.153.66.13 (machine-abc.mynetw.com)

When I try to connect and register to Naming context. I get and error that

```
retries exceeded.. can not connect to 192.168.64.39:2508
```

I decoded the IOR URI and found that it points to my private IP over LAN. So When I try to connect to it I get given exception. What shall I do So that on decode I get Public IP or HOST name.

So that I can access it remotely.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use, `-DOAIAddr=<Machine name IP>`

where `<Machine name IP>` can be host name or IP Address.

But Jacorb 2.3.1 has bug if we write Host name then not necessarily IOR will resolve to HOST name it will consist of IP address only.

Comment: JacORB 3.6 is the latest version and the problem should be solved there (if not, please raise a bug in the issue tracker)